# Fedora12 Slow USB 2.0 Write Speed, ehci_hcd module is missing

Tags: usb, fedora-12, performance, speed

I am using Fedora 12, the problem I am facing is USB 2.0 write speed.  I have a dual boot system with Windows XP and Fedora 12. USB 2.0 write speed in Windows XP is much faster then what I am getting in Fedora 12.

After searching Google I came to know that ehci_hcd module is missing/not present in my system. ehci_hcd module is neither loaded nor it is present in the available list of modules.

Can someone guide me how to fix this issue? Does ehci_hcd have something to do with USB 2.0 write speed?

Do I have to recompile the kernel and add/enable the ehci_hcd module?

Comment: By the way you should come to #Fedora channel on Freenode IRC network. Not like Superuser couldn't help but this is an answer editing pain always. Such problems are much easier to solve on IRC. Just a note/idea.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by missing? What happens if you simply try to modprobe? Like:

`su`
`modprobe ehci_hcd`
?

Comment: This is what i got.

WARNING: Deprecated config file /etc/modprobe.conf, all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/.
FATAL: Module ehci_hcd not found.

Comment: Hmm. Try checking your bios. `lsusb` outputs whether you got a 2.0 capable hub or not.

Comment: lsusb output

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub